# The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: KerasTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

def model_variant(model, num_feat_map, dim, network_type, p):
    print(network_type)
    if network_type == 'ConvLSTM':
        model.add(Permute((2, 1, 3)))
        model.add(Reshape((-1, num_feat_map * dim)))
        lstm_output = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, stateful=False))(model.output)
        model.add(lstm_output)
    if network_type == 'CNN':
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(p))
```

The error comes from adding model.add(lstm_output)

```
p=0.5 #Dropout
b = 1 #BatchNorm
print('building the model ... ')
model = Sequential()

if network_type=='CNN' or network_type=='ConvLSTM':
     model_conv(model, num_feat_map,p,b)
     model_variant(model, num_feat_map, dim, network_type,p)
if network_type=='LSTM':
    model_LSTM(model,p)

model_output(model)
model.summary()
```

and more details of the error:

```
      7     model.add(Reshape((-1, num_feat_map * dim)))
      8     lstm_output = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, stateful=False))(model.output)
----> 9     model.add(lstm_output)
     10 if network_type == 'CNN':
     11     model.add(Flatten())

File ~/miniconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py:517, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    515 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    516 try:
--> 517   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    518 finally:
    519   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File ~/miniconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:182, in Sequential.add(self, layer)
    179     layer = origin_layer
...
    184                   'Found: ' + str(layer))
    186 tf_utils.assert_no_legacy_layers([layer])
    187 if not self._is_layer_name_unique(layer):

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='bidirectional_11/concat:0', description="created by layer 'bidirectional_11'")
```

I am running an older code and here are the versions of tensorflow and keras that I'm using:
tensorflow                2.4.1
keras                     2.14.0

Comment: You cannot combine functional and sequential models that way, there is no need to.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thank you! but how to add lstm_output?

Comment: Simply model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, stateful=False)))